# .net InstallUtil utility - 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: .net, 64-bit, installutil

I've got a windows service compiled as AnyCPU.  I'm trying to get it into our installer to distribute.  However...   I am unclear on the difference between the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of InstallUtil.  Does anyone know what (if any) there are?

On my 64 bit machine, I can run either the $(WinDir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 or the $(WinDir)\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.

In both cases, the resulting service Process in Task Manager does not have the *32 flag applied to it.

Only the 32 bit InstallUtil works on 32 bit machines (obviously).

Is there a need to use the \Framework64\ version of InstallUtil?  What does it do differently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95.aspx), you are supposed to use the 64 bit version to install 64-bit and MSIL assemblies, but it doesn't say why.

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the 32-bit version of
>   the common language runtime (CLR) ships with only the 32-bit version
>   of the Installer tool, but the 64-bit version of the CLR ships with
>   both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Installer tool. When using the
>   64-bit CLR, use the 32-bit Installer tool to install 32-bit
>   assemblies, and the 64-bit Installer tool to install 64-bit and
>   Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) assemblies. Both versions of
>   the Installer tool behave the same.

I believe [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692753%28VS.85%29.aspx) explains why.   If you look at the bottom of the post, it explains some differences between the two and when to use the 32-bit intallutil.

> Installutil.exe is built for a specific platform, therefore it will
>   start as a 32 or 64-bit process and the related registry hive will be
>   updated. Note that if you have a snap-in built with the platform
>   switch, you will only be able to register it in one of the hives
>   (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: Perfect, that second one explains a hunch I had but wasn't able to confirm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this as well.  The issue was my VS2008 project was set to Platform Target: Any CPU.  No matter which InstallUtil.exe (32 or 64) I ran on the 64 bit OS it was installing as 64 bit.

I changed my project setting Target to x86 and then ran the 32 bit installutil.exe and everything works fine.  It now shows the *32 flag in Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing a 64-bit only assembly, the 32-bit InstallUtil won't be able to load it. You'll need to use the 64-bit version.